# EntityFramework and cascading delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascading-deletes

I have an issue with cascading delete. I would like to use it if possible but in some cases it is not working for me.
I have set up my **DbContext** to look like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{

    // Define our tables
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Center> Centers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCenter> UserCenters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Journal> Journal { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// static constructor (only gets called once)
    /// </summary>
    static DatabaseContext()
    {

        // Create the database and insert our records
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

        // Write our SQL to the debug window
        this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

        // Disable Lazy Loading
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    // Public static method for OWIN
    public static DatabaseContext Create()
    {
        return new DatabaseContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the inherited OnModelCreated method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder">The DbModelBuilder</param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Change default table names for Identity Framework
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");

        // Create mappings for Identity Framework
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(m => new { m.UserId, m.ProviderKey });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(m => m.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(m => new { m.RoleId, m.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasMany(m => m.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.RoleId);

        // Create our mappings
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCenter>().HasKey(m => new { m.UserId, m.CenterId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Center>().HasRequired(m => m.Company).WithMany(m => m.Centers).HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Center>().HasMany(m => m.Collections).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.CenterId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(m => m.Members).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        // Archive relationships
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(m => m.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(m => m.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Collection>().HasRequired(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Collection>().HasRequired(m => m.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Center>().HasRequired(m => m.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Center>().HasRequired(m => m.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ModifiedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Journal>().HasRequired(m => m.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are some archive mappings that I have that I have disabled Cascade on delete from. This is by design because I don't want to delete an item and it delete the user that created / modified it :)

If I delete a **Center** and it has some **Collections**, it deletes fine and the collections are removed. Same goes for if I delete a **User** and he has some **UserCenter**s both will be deleted fine, but if I try to delete a **Company** (which has Users and the users have UserCenters) it fails and I get an exception:

> exceptionMessage=The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database "melanite", table "dbo.Users", column 'CompanyId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I can see that it is moaning at the **CompanyId** field for the **User**, so I changed this line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(m => m.Members).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Because if I delete a **User**, I don't want it to delete the **Company** that the **User** belongs to.
But, on the other hand, if I delete a **Company** I do want it to delete the **User**s...

Does anyone know how I can fix my issue?

Comment: you have to update the user company id to null before delete the company

Comment: no, I want it to delete the users that belong to the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply configure your FK to delete on cascade:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(m => m.Members).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Cascading deletes always work in one direction, from the referenced table (Companies) to the referencing table (Users), so deleting a company will also delete its users, but deleting a user won't do anything to the referenced company.

Comment: I was literally just answering my own question. But cheers, this is exactly right.